# Construction of a stochastic process from a probability measure.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am interested in finding out how one can construct a Stochastic process given one knows every Nth order pdf?

I understand the extension theorem in so far as creating a measure on the product space but I don't understand how this can be extended to construct a stochastic process. How does one move from probability measure to creation of a random variable?

Comment: Kolomogorov's Extension Theorem (found in many texts on Probability Theory)  constructs a measure on a product space and then tells you that the projection maps on the product give you a stochastic process with given finite dimensional distributions. If you have difficulty with some steps in the proof you can appropriate questions.

Comment: Hi, I don't follow going from probability measure to random variable, what is the probability space? How do you define the random variable?